# Cannot partition my hard drive

Tags: partitioning, installation, centos

I'm trying to install CentOS 7 on my laptop, but I've got a problem partitioning the hard drive. Though here's writen the there is 2.49 MB of available space and 476.94 GB of total space, when I try to create new mount points (the partiotioning scheme is set on standard partition), I have the message that there is not enough space. What should I do ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the partition and recreating it?

Comment: Erm.. am I reading that right... you only have 2.49MB of free space, out of your 476.94GB capacity? CentOS needs more than 2.49MB of space... and Windows is not smart enough to partition HDD full of data. Some 3rd party partitioning tools may do the job, but you will need to make some space before you can partition that HDD.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've solved the problem. I created a new partition in Windows, then I used the free space created to create my mount points. Thank you very much for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2.49 MB of available space
i.e. 2.49 MB Free space.

You need more than 2 GB of available space to install centOS.